# PHP Error on Code it should not be running

Tags: php, classloader

First let me say sorry for the amount of code I'm posting below I'm going to try and keep it as short as possible but this is built on top of my MVC (lightweight-mvc)

Ok So my Problem is that for some reason php is throwing a fatal error on code that should not be being used in my current code,

So how this works I have my MVC witch used the first 2 parts of the url to know what its loading, the problem is I'm building a Moulder CMS into my MVC so it's boot strapping twice,

So here is my Problem,

`http://{domain}/admin/control/addon/uploader/method/uploadCheck/`

I'm using the above now let me explain a little into that the /admin/control are for the main MVC System it auto-loads the Admin controller then fires the controlAction method from the controller much the same as most MVC's,

The next part are URL paramters that build an array the same as GET or POST would

```
array('addon'=>'uploader', 'method'=>'uploadCheck')
```

So from that my control action will auto load as is the code below

```
public function controlAction(){
global $_URL;
if(cleanData::URL("addon")){
        $addonName = "addon_".cleanData::URL("addon");
        $methodName = (cleanData::URL("method"))? cleanData::URL("method")."Action" : "indexAction";
        echo $methodName;
        $addon = new $addonName();
        $addon->$methodName();
        return;
    }else{      
        $this->loadView("CMS/controll");
    }
}
```

`cleanData::URL` is an abstract method that just returns the value of the key provided though `addSlashes()`

So as you can see from the code below it will then use the autoloader to load the module(AKA addon)

Just so you can follow the auto loader works in a simpler version of the Zend Frame work autoloader _ so you have class name addon_admin that would be inside file admin.php that is in the folder addon so the autoloader will load addon/admin.php

So As above with my URL and controlAction it's loading addon/uploader.php and as such this is the contents

```
<?php
class addon_uploader extends Addons{

    public function uploadCheckAction(){
            echo 0;
    }

    public function uploaderAction(){
        if (!empty($_FILES)) {
            $tmpFile = $_FILES['Filedata']["tmp_name"];
            $newLock = "../uploads/".end(explode('/', $tmpFile).$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
            move_uploaded_file($tmpFileName, $newLock);

            $POSTback = array(
                'name' => $_FILES['Filedata']['name'],
                'type' => $_FILES['Filedata']['type'],
                'tmp_name' => $newLock,
                'error' => $_FILES['Filedata']['error'],
                'size' => $_FILES['Filedata']['size']
            );

            echo json_enocde($POSTback);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But as you can see from my URL its using the uploadCheckAction method witch for debugging i have set so it always says false (AKA 0),

But i seem to get this error:

```
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\FallenFate\addon\uploader.php on line 11
```

But line 11 is `$newLock = "../uploads/".end(explode('/', $tmpFile).$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);` witch should not be being used could any one provide any help into why this would occur and how i could fix it

Comment: ps : look at to  last 5th line of your uploader.php . There is a typo : `json_enocde();`

Comment: You have `echo $methodName;` while resolving the methodname. What does it output?

Comment: the echo is debugging, and the jdon_encode is a type, fixed that allready your fix worked the for fatel the json is not being called yet thats why i have not debuged it as of yet the problem was my class not loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`end()` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) needs an expression of a single variable (more precisely an array), but not a function return value or any other type of expression.

I think that's basically the cause of your error, more specifically with your code:

```
$newLock = "../uploads/".end(explode('/', $tmpFile).$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
```

you're even driving this far beyond any level of treatment PHP can cope with:

1. you concatenate an array with a string (which results in a string).
2. you run end() on that string - not on a variable, not even an array.

I have no clue what you try to do with the code, but I can try:

```
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$parts = explode('/', $tmpFile);
$last = end($parts);
$newLock = "../uploads/". $last . $filename;
```

Or probably even only this:

```
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$newLock = "../uploads/". $filename;
```

Comment: thanks,

That worked but its a little strange as other parts of my MVC codebase is using end(explode("/", "stringWithA/InSide")); and it returns InSide must be because the $tmpFile is not set thanks again when i can i will mark as an asnwer

Comment: @Martin Barker: Right, I'm on that as well, see my comment under your question directly. That needs more debugging.